# How do I create a console app in python?

Tags: python, console

I am attending a coding bootcamp and python is the primary language. For the final project, we were told to study and learn how to create console apps. I have searched online for tutorials and books but none seems to have beginner content. Where can I get the best tutorial on creating Python console apps? I have only done python for a month.

Comment: You mean an executable?

Comment: Something like Vim maybe

Comment:  Consider using [**`typer`**](https://typer.tiangolo.com/). It is the [`FastAPI`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) equivalent of creating terminal applications with python. Since, the question is closed, I cannot serve this as a new answer.

Answer (score 6):

Argparse for parsing command line arguments :

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Then for input you can use `input()`, or maybe curses.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html

Curses is a really powerful tool.
As an example here's `htop` that uses ncurses :

http://hisham.hm/htop/

Using `sys.stdin.readlines()` you can get the data that has been passed to your application, exemple :

```
cat myfile.txt | myapp.py
```

Then you can render your script executable using `chmod +x`, and adding a header in your script to the python binaries to use :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Then you could create an `alias`, or add your program to the `PATH`, so you could use it from anywhere on the system, like `ls`, `cat` or whatever you may think of...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me check them out